# Terraform aws_s3_bucket_policy syntax is unclear

Tags: terraform

In the [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket_policy.html) we are provided with the markup as attached below. I cant find any mention of what the purpose of the field "b" is and how it should be used in general.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "my_tf_test_bucket"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "b" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.b.id}"
  policy =<<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "MYBUCKETPOLICY",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_tf_test_bucket/*",
      "Condition": {
         "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "8.8.8.8/32"}
      } 
    } 
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"b" is simply the NAME of the resource that you are creating.

Terraform resources are defined in "blocks", and each resource block creates a resource of the given TYPE (first parameter) and NAME (second parameter). The combination of the type and name must be unique.

So, in your example, you are creating a resource of TYPE `aws_s3_bucket` and NAME `b`.

Each resource defined has an `id`, that you can use to refer this resource in other resources, using a syntax like TYPE.NAME.id, for example `${aws_s3_bucket.b.id}`

You can find further information in the doc here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html